# data pulling returning source conditional formatting

Tags: excel, data-visualization, conditional-formatting

Is there a way to copy over the exact hue of a conditionally formatted cell pulled using the formula below?

`=LARGE(A:A,1)`

I'm pulling a top 10 from hundreds of rows, each with a very specific hue which reveals another quantitative order, different than the criteria by which I'm ordering my top 10.

Perhaps an example would be clearer:

```
                        **Pets Owned**   ` - `   **Maintenance Level**
  Dogs           ` - `  ` 450            ` - `     8 
  Cats           ` - `  ` 350            ` - `     4
  Fish           ` - `  ` 150            ` - `     6
  Birds          ` - `  ` 100            ` - `     3
  Iguanas        ` - `  ` 5              ` - `     14
```

- Conditionally formatted by Column B w/ color scale from Green to Red

Let's say I wanted to pull only the top 3 highest Maintenance pets while maintaining the original formatting from column B, so what I want to see is:

**Maintenance Level**

```
14 {Red}       [Iguanas]
8 {Dark Green} [Dogs]
6 {Yellow}     [Fish]
```

- legend: desired value , {color} , [corresponding animal obtained thru Match/Index on adjacent column]

[image: the rightmost column colors need to match the leftmost cond. form. colors]

Sorry for the photo but windows is an absolute joke at screenshots (6+ steps to turn xml to jpg?!)

Comment: This would be clearer with screenshots...; are you trying to copy the colors of a formatted column to another column?

Comment: Took me 30 mins but I managed to upload a screenshot, after trying to save as webpage and convert to jpg online (came up blank), save prt scr to file and upload, convert xml worksheet to jpg, etc. Photo + email was the only that worked : / and because of my web filter at work I can't even see my own SC to check if it's fine.

Comment: Sorry to have put you through all this ;) You just sent us sensible business data, and you'll soon see security guys gathering around you.

Comment: Actually the data you see is downloadable from the [TfL Database](http://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/london-underground-performance-reports) and has nothing to do with the company I work for.

ps: I think you meant sensitive

Comment: yeah sensitive data... what I meant is you could send a ***simple image*** of what you want, not your actual data - sorry my words aren't accurate.

Comment: @DavidAndreiNed If you type `Snip` into the search bar below the windows start menu, you should see the Snipping tool which allows you to produce a `*.png` file, which can be copy/pasted into your message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Excel 2010 or later, you can do this with VBA, using the `DisplayFormat` property of the Cell.

Instead of a formula, I used a simple filter, but you could also use formulas.

I added a column headed MaintRank with a formula

```
=RANK(C2,$C$2:$C$6)
```

Then, for example, if I want the Top 3, I merely filter for `1`, `2` and `3`

Then use VBA to copy this to some new destination.  You can alter `rResults` in the code below to wherever you want.

You may also need to adjust `rTable` according to your real data

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyVisibleWithCFColor()
    Dim rData As Range, rResults As Range
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsResults As Worksheet
    Dim C As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

Set wsData = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsResults = Worksheets("sheet2")

With wsData
    Set rData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
End With
Set rResults = wsResults.Cells(1, 1)

Set rData = rData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

rResults.Resize(columnsize:=rData.Columns.Count).EntireColumn.Clear
Set rResults = rResults(1)

rData.Copy rResults

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Set rResults = rResults.CurrentRegion
rResults.EntireColumn.ClearFormats
J = 0
For I = 1 To rData.Areas.Count
    For Each C In rData.Areas(I).Columns(2).Cells
        Debug.Print C.Address
        J = J + 1
        rResults.Rows(J).Interior.Color = C.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Next C
Next I

End Sub
```

---

In the screen shot below, you can see the original data on Sheet1 and the copied results on Sheet2.  On sheet1 I selected to return the items ranked 2, 4 and 5 and, on sheet2, the macro also colored in the entire row.  Obviously you can change that, and you don't need to also copy the "rank" columns if you don't need it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If me not mistaken, OP wants this:
[image]

I have a poor solution for you if you wish to play with Excel VBA...

It implies to build your own "color-format" function in VBA :)  `makeColor`

```vb
Public Function makeColor(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal min As Integer, ByVal max As Integer)
    Dim r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer
    ' you  must fine-tune the cases as you like
    b = 0
    If (x < (min + max) / 2) Then
      r = 255
      g = 0
    Else
      g = 255
      r = 0
    End If
    makeColor = RGB(r, g, b)
End Function
```

Say your data is in "color" tab and stands in range (B1:B5); hard coded values "0" and "500" represent min and max in your data and must be defined programmatically too:

```vb
Public Sub cpyColor()
    Dim wkRange As Range
    Dim c As Range        
    Set wkRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("color").Range("$B$1:$B$5")
    For Each c In wkRange
      c.Interior.Color = makeColor(c.Value, 0, 500)
      c.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = c.Interior.Color
    Next
End Sub
```

With my 2 cases `makeColor` function it gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm sure it works as the logic is sound, but a bit too 'hard-coded' for what I wish to do (would have to do the same for multiple columns).

I could use the same defined color range for multiple ranges, correct? It sounds half automated so at least there's a method that works and is somewhat scalable. :)

Comment: You can replicate same color to neighbors with `c.Offset(0, 2)....`; `c.Offset(0, 3)....` ; `c.Offset(0, 4)....` ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done without VBA, but as alternative you can change the conditional formatting rules of the destination to match those of the source

[image]

Comment: this is a neat non-VBA solution that deserves some praise! :)